# The CarouselView in Xamarin is broken. Anyone know how to fix this or report it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout

I have a Picker that is part of a CarouselView. When the Picker appears in a CarouselView, it appears to selects a size proportional to all the items in the ItemsSource, like a list box, and not the size of a single unit, as you'd expect in a Picker (drop down).

This illustrates the issue. The Pickers are identical. Both sit inside a StackLayout. One is not inside a Carousel, the other is:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.MainPage">
<StackLayout>
    <Picker>
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>California</x:String>
                <x:String>Texas</x:String>
                <x:String>New York</x:String>
                <x:String>Arizona</x:String>
                <x:String>Alabama</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
    </Picker>
    <CarouselView Margin="20,5" IsBounceEnabled="False" Loop="False">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:PageViewModel">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Picker>
                        <Picker.ItemsSource>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                <x:String>California</x:String>
                                <x:String>Texas</x:String>
                                <x:String>New York</x:String>
                                <x:String>Arizona</x:String>
                                <x:String>Alabama</x:String>
                            </x:Array>
                        </Picker.ItemsSource>
                    </Picker>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Do Nothing</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

The result looks likes this:

[image: Carousel Bug]

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: a screenshot illustrating the problem would be useful

Comment: What are you trying to do? After running your code, it didn't crash  on my side.

Comment: I didn't say it crashed. Read the description. The two pickers should occupy the same space in the StackLayout - namely, the size of one item. The Picker, when it's hosted in the Carousel, occupies a height equal to all of the items in the list. If I were to put all 50 states in the Picker, the height of the control would be 1,600. And once you click on the Picker that has the wrong height, it returns to the normal height.

Comment: Yes, the same code on the Android device won't appear such problem. You can post a issue in [github for Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues). Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I've posted it to https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15165. If you have additional information, or just verification, would you add it to the thread. Thanks.